# Are international US REU candidates considered "independent researchers" under B-1/B-2 visa category?

Tags: united-states, visa, research

US [REU programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_Experiences_for_Undergraduates) sometimes accept "self-funded" international students. Such international candidates do not receive any financial assistance from the host university but participate in research.

1. **Would that classify as "independent research", under the B-1/B-2 visa category?**
2. For example, [this](https://internationalaffairs.uchicago.edu/bandvisawaiver) University of Ohio page mentions:

   > A visitor conducting independent research. Independent research means the use of University facilities **without any affiliation or appointment**. NOTE: a visitor with affiliation or appointment should consider coming on a J-1 visa, even if no payment is made to the visitor by the University.

   Per the US law, would an international REU candidate be considered **affiliated** with or **appointed** by the host university?

Comment: The U of Chicago does not make the laws. They are just giving you an overview of what the law is.

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

If you are paid for the program, it would be considered employment and the visas you mentioned would not be for that. https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html

There are other visas you can apply for though.

Answer (score -1):

Self-funded participation in an REU program should be an [acceptable use](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/B-1%20permissible%20activities.pdf) of a B-1 visa. [The regulations](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5;node=8%3A1.0.1.2.18) do not define "independent research", but in §214.2(b)(7) prohibits using a B-1 visa to enroll in a course of study:

> An alien who is admitted as, or changes status to, a B-1 or B-2
>   nonimmigrant on or after April 12, 2002, or who files a request to
>   extend the period of authorized stay in B-1 or B-2 nonimmigrant status
>   on or after such date, violates the conditions of his or her B-1 or
>   B-2 status if the alien enrolls in a course of study.

"Independent research" in this law does not mean "research in a vacuum", it means "not in connection with employment" and "not enrolled in a course of study". The regulations also do not refer to "affiliation" or "appointment". A given university might impose stricter requirements on persons wishing to use university facilities.

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/105016).

Comment: I'm relying on the law: that answer relies on a notion of "benefit" that isn't supported by the law.

Comment: The notion of benefit, however, is so uniformly reported by educational institutions that it must be derived from some litigation (which I cannot find) or at least from executive policy (which is reflected in https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf).  A B visa applicant cannot in general challenge the executive's interpretation or implementation of the law in court.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of whether you are paid, conducting research for the benefit of a US institution constitutes enough of an affiliation that it is not "independent."  Independent research is something like visiting the institution's library for your own research.  Participating in a collegial research project organized by the institution is not "independent."

In its [flyer concerning business visitors (PDF)](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf), the US Department of State says:

> Researcher: Independent research, no salary/income from a U.S. based source, **or benefit to U.S. institution.**

(Emphasis added.)

As noted elsewhere, the requirement concerning benefit is not to be seen in the statute nor the regulations.  I suspect that this interpretation is based on some litigation (or perhaps an administrative determination in the immigration court system), but I cannot find that at the moment.  Regardless, an applicant for a B visa cannot generally challenge the consular officer's determination, so the State Department's interpretation of the law is effectively the last word as far as you're concerned.

Comment: Downvoter: why?